# match.call function with no arguments

Tags: r

I'm exploring the source code of `glm` function that I got with `getAnywhere(glm)`:

```
function (formula, family = gaussian, data, weights, subset, 
          na.action, start = NULL, etastart, mustart, offset, control = list(...), 
          model = TRUE, method = "glm.fit", x = FALSE, y = TRUE, singular.ok = TRUE, 
          contrasts = NULL, ...) 
{
  cal <- match.call()
  ...
  structure(c(fit, list(call = cal, formula = formula, terms = mt, 
                        data = data, offset = offset, control = control, method = method, 
                        contrasts = attr(X, "contrasts"), xlevels = .getXlevels(mt, 
                                                                                mf))), class = c(fit$class, c("glm", "lm")))
}
```

I don't understand what the `cal` variable does. I asked this to ChatGPT and this was it's answer:

> The `structure()` function receives the `call` variable as one of its
> arguments because it is including the original call to the function in
> the structured object being created. By including the original call,
> information about the arguments and parameters used to create the
> object is preserved. This can be useful for reference or debugging
> purposes, since you can access the original call and see how the
> object was created.
>
> In short, the `call` variable contains the original call to the function
> and is passed to the `structure()` function to include the call
> information in the resulting structured object.
>
> [Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)]

I don't understand what means "the original call to the function" and why `match.call` was used with no arguments.

Comment: Instead of ChatGPT, take a look at `?match.call` and then run the example `fun` in the 'Examples' section. Then try it but changing the `fun` `x`, `lower` and `upper` arguments - that should give a practical example of what `match.call` does that will get away from the technical details. Also note the shortening of `upper=` to `u=` in the example, and then what is shown in the output for the CALL attribute.

Comment: And generally in R when you call a function without specifying arguments, the defaults are used. You can see these in the function call **Usage** section at the `?match.call` help page: `match.call(definition = sys.function(sys.parent()), call = sys.call(sys.parent()), expand.dots = TRUE, envir = parent.frame(2L))`. If you have questions about some of these, you can see their help pages, `?sys.parent`, `parent.frame`, etc. For a somewhat deeper overview, see the [`match.call` subsection of Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html#match.call)

Comment: You should first study [the language definiton](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html) and `help("call")` to understand what a call is.

Comment: @thelatemail I've read that documentartion before, but I'm not familiar with the `sys.` functions so I gave up. Now I was running the example as you said and finally I think I understand what `match.call` does. Thanks!